# Another 'R could not find function "ggline"'

Tags: ggplot2, ggpubr

Before you give me the boilerplate advice about looking into loading packages, let me just say that I have loaded all of my packages. I have read previous posts about this and nothing has worked so far: I removed 'ggplot2','ggpubr','plyr','tidyverse', basically all of my packages and reinstalled them, with dependencies. I have tried require(ggplot2) and require(ggpubr). And I'm still getting this issue.

My code was working a couple of days ago, but I closed R and now I'm getting an error.

```
tiff(file="P:/School/Dissertation/Analysis/Results/Figures/means_GNG_PACC_slope.tiff")
ggline(plotcogs, x="TIME", y="GNG_PACC_slope", add=c("mean_sd","jitter"), color="STIM", palette=c("#00AFBB","#FC4E07"), size=0.75, point.size=1.25, xlab="Time from start of stim (min)", ylab="Mean", legend="right")
dev.off()
```

Error:

```
Error in ggline(plotcogs, x = "TIME", y = "GNG_PACC_slope", add = c("mean_sd",  : 
  could not find function "ggline"
```

Any ideas why this would work recently but now isn't, in spite of me removing/reinstalling/loading the packages?

Example data block:

```
PARTIDA ORDER   VISIT   STIM    TIME    GNG_PACC_slope
1   1   5   1   1   -0.149925037
1   1   5   1   2   0.239808153
1   1   5   1   3   -0.299401198
1   1   4   2   1   -0.3003003
1   1   4   2   2   0.4
1   1   4   2   3   -0.4
4   2   4   1   1   -0.133333333
4   2   4   1   2   0.239808153
4   2   4   1   3   -0.085689803
```

Comment: Are you using RStudio?
AND show us where your `.libPath()` is pointing to? and the value of your `Sys.geten("R_USER")`?

Comment: and just for completeness do you also get the exact same error when using `ggpubr::ggline(...` under the assumption that this is the `ggline` function from that package?

Comment: I use RStudio to write my code but not to run it so I enter it directly into RGui. .libPaths() returns “C:/Users/my.name/Documents/R/win-library/4.0” and “C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library”. Sys.getenv(“R_USER”) returns “C:\\Users\\my.name\\Documents”. And adding ggpubr:: to my code results in this error: “Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]] : namespace ‘ellipsis’ 0.3.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.3.2 is required”.

Comment: hmmm .... that last part looks like a good hint - seems your library is "silently" dying on you in a dependency sense when you load it or run a function from it (w `library` or `require`) => I suggest u try and do the required update of the `ellipsis` package 
last hint: `ellipsis` can be tricky to install/update in case you have libraries often from the tidyverse that you maybe load at startup (eg in yr .Rprofile) so make sure there is nothing like that in your setup - I usually also avoid RStudio for these kinds of updates and stick to `R --vanilla`

Comment: Thanks @GWD, that ended up being helpful. It turned out that ellipsis and rlang both needed to be updated but weren't updating with update.packages() - so I just manually removed them and re-installed. Thanks for your help!